# Can a product's attribute store several values for the same product or do I have to do something else (Magento 1.9)?

Tags: magento-1.9, module, database, model

I will explain with general terms the situation:

I have some products which should have 1-8 values for the same attribute and in the same product.
For example:

SKU 55720,

Name of Attribute: Norm,

Value of Norm: [ISO4567, ESI8909, RA4545],

Then I will develop a module for filter where the customer will be able of filter products that meet his selection. (very simple)

Then my issue/doubt is:
Can an attribute store multiple values for a same product?
If not, what would you do?

I have thought that if only can store one value, I can add multiple values if I separate them using commas, and in consecuense, when I develop the module, I will check if a product has one or more of the values searched.

Answer (score 0):

you can store the data in the form of a comma separated list. While search for the filters you can use in_array($filter,$productAttributeValues) to check if the product matches the filter.

Anyway its not robust way of doing it as it will slow down the search.